# Como calcular campos en symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Buenos dias quisiera preguntar si hay alguna forma de que se pueda calcular el valor de 2 campos en symfony y anadirlo a otro en la base de datos.

En python hay un decorador @property, en symfony hay alguna forma de hacerlo???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependera del concepto al que te estas ajustando, existen en Symfony multiples eventos los cuales puedes estar escuchando, ejemplo, el persist de un entity o si tu mandas un evento en el systema puedes estarlo escuchando y hacer una operacion distinta, tambien existen comandos, los cuales, puedes aprovechar para hacer operaciones en otra base de datos o mandar mensajes o eventos de manera asyncrona